# Iterate a command over each column of a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file like following..

```
N A C T C C G G T G T C G G T C T C G T A G G C C A T T T T A G A A G C G A A T A A A T C G A T G N A T T C G A N C N C N N N N N N N N A T C G N N A G A G C T C G T A N G C C G T C T T C T G C T T G A 
N T C T A C G G T G T C G G T C T C G T A G C C T A T C G G G T A G C A G A G C T T A T C G A T G A A T T C G A G C T C G G T T T C A G A T T G G C A G A G C T C G T A N T G C G G C C T T C G G C T G A 
N G T T A C G G T G T C G G T C T C G T A G T G A G T T G A C C T C C G C C C A G T A T C G A T G A A T T C G A G C T C G T T T T C A G A T C G G A A G A G C T C G T C N G C C G T C T T C T G C T T G A 
N A G A T C G G T G T C G G T C T C G T A G A T G A T C T G G C A A T A G C G C C C A T C G A T G A A T T C G A G C T C G T T T T C A G A T C G G A A G A G C T C G T A N G C G G T C T T C T C C T T G A
```

I want to iterate a command over each column of the file. That is

```
awk '{h[$1]++};END{for (k in h)print k, h[k]}' sample2.fa | sort -r -n -k2
```

The output file would be like

```
 N 4  A 2 ..
      T 1 ..
      G 1  ..
```

I've tried a lot to solve this and came here for suggestions.

Comment: You want the count of how many times each letter appears in each column? Where each column of output is the counts for that column?

Comment: exactly ! and sorting those in reverse order, like shown.

Comment: Sorting each column's entries in reverse order?

Comment: after running the command before pipe I will get the information of how many times each character is repeated in the first column, then sort works to sort it in ascending order based on the number of occurrences.

Comment: Showing sample input and valid output for that input would help.

Comment: @anubhava I've just shown the sample data. It is a very large file. The sample output was from running the oneliner on whole data file.

Comment: @anubhava The (paired) columns in the output match the columns in the input is my understanding.

Comment: That one-liner wouldn't generate columns of data. Did you run it for the first two columns and manually combine them?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yep! Please refer to the edited (expected output modified according to the given data) question

Comment: @Cyrus Of course I've read these, but the conversation is going on. As I am a new user I do not have sufficient reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script uses `awk` to count all letters in the input file and `sort` to perform two rounds of sorting and then again `awk` to format the output:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    l[$i]++;
    a[i, $i]++;
    if (NF > n) {n = NF};
  }
}
END{
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j in l) {
      if (a[i, j] > 0) {print i, j, a[i, j]};
    }
  }
}
' sample.fa | sort -k 3 -n -r | sort -k 1 -n -s |\ 
awk '
{
  col=$1;
  a[col]++;
  row = a[col];
  l[col, row] = $2;
  n[col, row] = $3;
  if (maxCol < col) {maxCol = col};
  if (maxRow < row) {maxRow = row};
}
END {
  for (row = 1; row <= maxRow; row++) {
    for (col = 1; col <= maxCol; col++) {
      printf "%s\t%s\t", l[col, row], n[col, row];
    }
    printf "\n";
  }
}'
```

Output (first 10 letters from sample input):

```
N 4 A 2 C 2 T 3 A 2 C 4 G 4 G 4 T 4 G 4 
    T 1 T 1 A 1 T 1           
    G 1 G 1     C 1
```

Comment: Excellent. I can modify the output according to my need. Thank you very much

Comment: I keep feeling like this is doable in a single call to awk but that probably requires a fair bit of contorting and redundant data collection.

Answer (score 1):

Double awk array will do the job, except the final formatting

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {a[i,$i]++; codes[$i]=1} } END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) for(c in codes) if((i,c) in a) print i, c, a[i,c]}'
```

you'll get, first digit is column number,

```
1 N 4
2 A 2
2 G 1
2 T 1
3 C 2
3 G 1
3 T 1
4 A 1
4 T 3
```

you can pipe to sort to get the required order

```
... | sort -k1n -k3nr
```

here sorting by the first value in ascending order and third value be descending.

Comment: Thank you. This helps me a lot.